# convert url get parameters to url segment in nginx

Tags: nginx, server, url-rewriting

I have this URL https://example.com/user?param1=value1&param2=value2&param3=value3

and have it to go to  https://example.com/user/value1/value2/value3 on the Nginx server.

Just FYI it is WordPress site and I have added the following rule in the Nginx config file.

```
location ~ /user/ {
    if ($args ~* "^param1=(\d+)&param3=(\d+)&param3=(\d+)") {
    set $param1 $1;
    set $param2 $1;
    set $param3 $1;
    set $args '';
    rewrite ^.*$ /user/$param1/$param2/$param3 permanent;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution has two errors, 1) the `location` does not match `/user`, and 2) the `rewrite` is also appending the original arguments.

This could be fixed by using an exact match `location` and a trailing `?` on the `rewrite`. For example:

```
location = /user {
    ...
    rewrite ^ /user/$param1/$param2/$param3? permanent;
}
```

---

However, the `map` statement is a cleaner and extensible solution, for example:

```
map $request_uri $redirect {
    default                                                          0;
    ~*^/user?param1=(?<p1>\d+)&param2=(?<p2>\d+)&param3=(?<p3>\d+)$  /user/$p1/$p2/$p3;
}

server {
    ...
    if ($redirect) { return 301 $redirect; }
    ...
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.